# request() in python seems to block the update of the variable that I want to send in my code

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib, httpconnection, httplib

So I have this code that which receives data via RF Receiver constantly.

```
key = 'my api key'
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)

def rfWaterLevel():
    rfWaterLevelArray = ser.readline().strip().split()
    if len(rfWaterLevelArray) == 5:
         rfWaterLevelVal = float(rfWaterLevelArray[4])
         params = urllib.urlencode({'field1':rfWaterLevelVal, 'key':key})
         headers = {"Content-typZZe" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept":"text/plain"}
         conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("api.thingspeak.com:80")
         conn.request("POST", "/update", params, headers)
         response = conn.getresponse()
         data = response.read()
         conn.close()
while True:
    try:
        rfWaterLevel()
        time.sleep(3)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "caught keyboard interrupt"
        sys.exit()
```

In terms of sending data and updating thingspeak its working. However there is a big flaw. The rfWaterLevelVal variable that is being sent is not updating at all accordingly to the data being received. So if initially the rf data received is 30 thus making rfWaterLevelVal 30, then the next round of data is 40, the data being sent is still stuck at 30.

I tried to comment out code line by line to see what is making this happen and it seems as though this "freeze" in updating the rfWaterLevelArray & rfWaterLevelVal variable occurs at the line...

```
 conn.request("POST", "/update", params, headers)
```

any help on why my rfWaterLevelArray or rfWaterLevelVal variable is not being updated at all after this code being run once?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an answer, but your Content-Type header has a typo.

Comment: Suggestion: instead of commenting out lines, which changes the program, insert print statements.  The code you presented cannot possibly run and doesn't make much sense.  These variables are undefined: `ser, rfWaterLevelTemp, key`.  You are using `rfWaterLevel` as both a function name and a local variable name (not a bug but bad style).  The variable `data` never gets used (not a bug but pointless).

Comment: Try `conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("api.thingspeak.com:80", timeout=5)`, to confirm if the request times out and `headers` should end with a `}`.

Comment: @Paul Cornelius I've left the definitions of `ser` out as it is literally just
    `ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)`
the `key` variable I left out due to the fact that it's an API key that I did not want to share (since it's private).

@shiva I have just tried that and it seems to not time out? The data constantly sent but it's the same data(the initial data) that is being sent over and over again repeatedly.
I totally forgot to rename my function name. :P

Answer (score 0):

The value of `rfWaterLevel` isn't getting updated because you aren't updating it.  Every time you call `rfWaterLevel` (the function) you execute this statement:

`rfWaterLevel = float(rfWaterLevelTemp[4])`

Then you do something with that value, but you don't show where `rfWaterLevelTemp[4]` comes from.  Unless it gets changed somewhere, it will always be the same.  You will be sending the same value over and over again.  Perhaps you meant to write:

`rfWaterLevel = float(rfWaterLevelArray[4])`

which I think would send the latest data you got from the serial port.

Comment: Sorry, I keep typing up typos (as this code is in my raspberry pi, I had to copy it over etc...) but I have editted the code now, and it should not have typos. 

That IS what I meant and that is what I have done. So any ideas on why it still blocks the update of the array? (Definitely not the rf transmitter side as it is sending the things right and I am receiving it correctly as well. Plus, when I run my code without sending it over the cloud the `rfWaterLevel` variable gets updated as frequently the data is being sent in.

Comment: When you use the word "block" or "freeze", to me you imply that the program stops executing at the `conn.request` line.  But you also keep saying the variable "rfWaterLevelVal" doesn't change, so I guess I'm not clear on the problem.  You say rfWaterLevelVal does change when you don't transmit to the cloud, as if the function call conn.request magically reverts it to its original value.  That makes zero sense.  How do you know when it's changing and when it's not?  I would insert a print statement right after the conn.request line and print the value of "params".

Comment: Ok to explain in detail on how I know the values change. The data being sent from the other device via RF is the water level data. Thus the water level data changes as the water level changes. I change the water level and the data being sent changes (checked through serial monitor on the other computer). When I run the code without the entire cloud transmission part, the data received replicates the data being sent which is what I want. However when I start the cloud transmission the rfWaterLevelVal is not update after the initial rfWaterLevelVal received. That is the part I am confused on.

Comment: In terms of adding print statements everywhere to debug, I have done that and seen all the values my self. Nothing seems to be out of the ordinary therefore I thought somehow that specific line of code is somehow not allowing the rfWaterLevelArray to be updated (thus not received the new data incoming).